# Best practice for async communication between services

Tags: android, binding, service, design-patterns, messenger

What's best/good service binding/communication practice in the following scenario (I hope the title is somewhat meaningful):

A business layer (BL) comprising several service methods that share (as common communication endpoint) an asynchronous socket service (SS) which may be bound by those methods and used for socket IO.

E.g. the BL grabs SL and invokes send(message) and then awaits a response.

I used callbacks and the binder pattern at first. As I had some problems with a clear design using the binder pattern (lack of a message queue and everything done in the main thread), I am now trying the message pattern.

So basically, BL services and the SL service now have a Messenger and a corresponding handler:

```
private final IncomingHandler incomingHandler = new IncomingHandler();
private final Messenger messengerReceiver = new Messenger(incomingHandler);
private class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
  @Override
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
  ...
  }
}
```

One of the BLs is an AbstractAccountAuthenticator subclass implementing

```
addAccount(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, String accountType, String authTokenType, String[] requiredFeatures, Bundle options){
     ...
     if(socketConnectionState != null){
        Bundle authBundle = new Bundle();
        authBundle.putString("password", password);
        authBundle.putString("username", account.name);
        Message message = Message.obtain(null, SocketConnectionHandler.SEND_REQUEST, authBundle);
        message.replyTo = messengerReceiver;
        socketConnectionState.getMessenger().send(message);
...}
```

which also uses the SL to obtain the authToken.
The addAccount() method either requires to return the result (the authToken) immediately in a Bundle or to call the response callback methods instead.
Now if I request the auth token inside addAccount via SL, how would I handle to pass back the result?

The main problem here is that the result is not returned to the calling method (addAccount()) but to the messengerReceiver handler.

The only way I could think of is a BlockingQueue which is offered the response by the message handler and which is then taken inside the addAccount() method but this really feels uberugly.
Other ideas? Right approach at all?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem only arises if you state the premiss, that responding is the message handler's concern.

I recently had the same problem at work. We solved it by extending the argument list of message handler

```
public interface MessageHandler {
    public void receivedMessage(Message message, ResponseChannel channel);
}

interface ResponseChannel {
    public void respond(Message response);
}

interface Message {}
```

Of course one could introduce a member variable in each instance of `MessageHandler`, but that would remove the statelessness - in the end, the principle behind both approaches is the same.

Still, there's another possibility.

## Separation of concern

As I said before assigning the  additional responsibility of answering the response to the message handler leaves a bad taste. 
The message handler already has the responsibility of receiving incoming messages.

He handles the incoming message, which should be a short process of extracting relevant parameters and forwarding the message to the interested parties or calling the appropriate methods on the model or on a controller.

It should be a short and non-exhaustive process, because message handlers logically aren't part of the send/receive component, but are registered there and share a thread or thread pool with all the other message handler and their invocations.

So how should one handle responses then? It follows that, if it's not in the handlers responsibility, the parties that are notified from the handler should take action.

```
public interface MessageHandler {
    public void receivedMessage(Message message, ApplicationContext context);
}

interface ApplicationContext {
    public void notifyUserJoined(String name);
}

interface Message {
    public String getUser();
}
```